# Is it allowed to handle threads inside MBeans?

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb, jmx

According to EJB specification, EJBs should not handle threads inside its classes. Thread handling is done by the EJB container. But I am wondering what is the specification rules for MBeans regarding the thread handling? Is it okay to handle threads or add synchronized methods/blocks inside JMX MBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok. There's no equivalent restriction in JMX.